# PHP website database Integration with Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I want my PHP website database to sync with Salesforce objects. Please guide me for achieving this task.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Salesforce rest api's in your php code for push/pull data from salesforce. For this you need not to do any coding in salesforce because salesforce is having lots of built in apis. But you need to make a strategy to reduce number of api calls.

If you want 2 way sync i.e. if anything get updated in salesforce should also update in your database then you have to write outbound service in salesforce. Assuming you already have api written for your website.

For more detail on salesforce apis, you can go through salesforce documentation.